# How to move aggregate across sets of rows in spreadsheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Raw date is set of a value assigned to each sub-second.
The next Aggregate table is the average value for all sub-seconds of each second >> [`avg(b2:b11)`]
Copying the same formula to the next row in the aggregate table, will be  [`avg(b3:b12)`]
How to Jump 10 rows (or n number of rows), for the next cell (following row) in the aggregate table.

[image: raw to aggregate]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the screenshot. Formulas are on the screen.
[image: AVG]